# "ecb" doesn't work whit Cordova and PushPlugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I've tried to register my device using pushNotification, using a demo.
It doesn't work. Print "Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo" and "registering android" and look the alert "OK" (successHandler function works). The problem is that doesn't work the "ecb". Why? Can you help me?

The plugin that I've installed with Cordova are: PushPlugin, Device, Notification, InAppBrowser and Network Information.

I've tried the app on my LG L9 and on emulator. Same problem.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
var pushNotification;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available

function onDeviceReady() {
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
    $("#app-status-ul").append("<li>registering android</li>");
    window.plugins.pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
        "senderID": "my_id",
        "ecb": "onNotificationGCM"
    }); // required!
} else {
    $("#app-status-ul").append("<li>registering iOS</li>");
    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
        "badge": "true",
        "sound": "true",
        "alert": "true",
        "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
    }); // required!
}
}

// handle APNS notifications for iOS

function onNotificationAPN(e) {
if (e.alert) {
    navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
}
if (e.sound) {
    var snd = new Media(e.sound);
    snd.play();
}
if (e.badge) {
    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
}
}
// handle GCM notifications for Android

function onNotificationGCM(e) {
navigator.notification.alert(e.event);
switch (e.event) {
case 'registered':
    if (e.regid.length > 0) {
        navigator.notification.alert(e.regid);
        // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
        $("#app-status-ul").append("<li>regID = " + e.regid +"</li>");
        sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId",e.regid);
    }
    break;
case 'message':
    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
    if (e.foreground) {
        navigator.notification.alert('--INLINE NOTIFICATION--');
        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + e.soundname);
        my_media.play();
    } else { // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
        if (e.coldstart) navigator.notification.alert('--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--');
        else navigator.notification.alert('--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--');
    }
    navigator.notification.alert(e.payload.message);
    navigator.notification.alert('MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt);
    break;
case 'error':
    navigator.notification.alert('ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg);
    break;
default:
    navigator.notification.alert('EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is');
    break;
}
}

function tokenHandler(result) {
navigator.notification.alert(result, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId", result);
sessionStorage.setItem("notificationServer", "APNS");
// Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
// here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
}

function successHandler(result) {
navigator.notification.alert(result, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId", result);
sessionStorage.setItem("notificationServer", "GCM");
}

function errorHandler(error) {
navigator.notification.alert(error, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
}

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

     </script>
    <div id="home">
        <div id="app-status-div">
            <ul id="app-status-ul">
                <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: onNotificationGCM must have scope in window. See logcat to show more error

Comment: That is? I don't understand, can you give an example?

Comment: What platform and device you run plugin? Note: PushPlugin not working in IOS emulator, you must test on real device. In Android, you can test it in emulator with google API target(included google service for GCM working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Hanh Le said, you need to have the ecb-callback to be accessible from the window-object

Like this

```
    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
       "badge": "true",
       "sound": "true",
       "alert": "true",
       "ecb": "window.onNotificationAPN"
    }); // required!
```

and then replace

```
     function onNotificationAPN(e) {
```

with

```
    window.onNotificationAPN = function(e) {
```

EDIT: here is the whole code you posted edited in a way I think should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
var pushNotification;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available

function onDeviceReady() {
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
        $("#app-status-ul").append("<li>registering android</li>");
        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
           "senderID": "my_id",
           "ecb": "window.onNotificationGCM"
        }); // required!
    } else {
         $("#app-status-ul").append("<li>registering iOS</li>");
         pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true",
            "alert": "true",
            "ecb": "window.onNotificationAPN"
         }); // required!
   }
}

// handle APNS notifications for iOS

window.onNotificationAPN = function(e) {
   if (e.alert) {
      navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
   }
   if (e.sound) {
      var snd = new Media(e.sound);
      snd.play();
   }
   if (e.badge) {
      pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
   }
}
// handle GCM notifications for Android

window.onNotificationGCM = function(e) {
   navigator.notification.alert(e.event);
   switch (e.event) {
      case 'registered':
      if (e.regid.length > 0) {
          navigator.notification.alert(e.regid);
          // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this    device
         // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
         $("#app-status-ul").append("<li>regID = " + e.regid +"</li>");
         sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId",e.regid);
     }
     break;
     case 'message':
        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
         if (e.foreground) {
            navigator.notification.alert('--INLINE NOTIFICATION--');
            // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
            var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + e.soundname);
            my_media.play();
         } else { // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
           if (e.coldstart) navigator.notification.alert('--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--');
           else navigator.notification.alert('--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--');
         }
         navigator.notification.alert(e.payload.message);
         navigator.notification.alert('MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt);
         break;
    case 'error':
       navigator.notification.alert('ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg);
    break;
    default:
       navigator.notification.alert('EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is');
    break;
  }
}

function tokenHandler(result) {
   navigator.notification.alert(result, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
   sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId", result);
   sessionStorage.setItem("notificationServer", "APNS");
   // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
   // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
}

function successHandler(result) {
   navigator.notification.alert(result, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
   sessionStorage.setItem("deviceId", result);
   sessionStorage.setItem("notificationServer", "GCM");
}

function errorHandler(error) {
   navigator.notification.alert(error, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

</script>
<div id="home">
    <div id="app-status-div">
        <ul id="app-status-ul">
            <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And for Android? I've tried this: `window.onNotificationGCM = function(e) {`  - - - Then i've edited this `window.plugins.pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, { "senderID": "my_id", "ecb": "window.onNotificationGCM"});` and again in this `plugins.pushNotification.register` and again with this `pushNotification.register`, but they doesn't work..

Comment: I've tried also with other combinations, but nothing. I'll wait for your advice.

Comment: on iOS, testing the notification can't be done in the simulator, but on your android device it should work. How are you sending the notifications? and if your device registers correctly, can you see the incoming notifications in logcat?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong.. But with the function "onNotificationGCM" he should print (using `$("#app-status-ul").append("<li>regID = " + e.regid +"</li>")`) the registration ID? Now, I'm writing with tablet and I can't make changes to the code. In logcat I don't see nothing about "regID". But, for Android, what is the right method? I will do further testing after the 13.

Comment: In locgat I don't see nothing about "regID" beacuase I don't "print" the id in a log, but in a "ul" just with the `$("#app-status-ul").append(...`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I thought your device registered corerctly but didn't receive the notifications. I've got this plugin working on iOS but have never tried it on android, so I'm not exactly sure what is wrong here. The code looks good to go and if the successHandler-function gets called it implies something did happen correctly. I'll edit my original answer for some clarity

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your patience. I used your code, changed the id and added this `if (e.regid.length > 0) {code .. navigator.notification.alert(error, null, 'Alert', 'yes');} else navigator.notification.alert(error, null, 'Alert', 'no');` to print at least an alert, but it doesn't work. I don't understand much, I'm still learning, but the problem couldn't be in the PushNotification.js file? Is this: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/Example/www/PushNotification.js - PS: I've used this guide at first: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: After I try to study this plugin, but if you help me, I'd be grateful

Comment: Nothing. I searched on Google and I've tried other guide, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Up! Help me please :(

Comment: I'm trying to but it's a bit hard, I see ne obvious faults in the code I posted, I tried the code on iOS and it works. Have you tried to copy the whole example project on [github](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/tree/master/Example/www) and see if that works?

Comment: I've download this example: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin then I've replaced "phonegapp.js" with "cordova.js".  The app doesn't print the id, it prints only "- Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo - deviceready event received - registering Android - success:OK"..

Answer (score 0):

you can put your `onNotificationGCM` function outside of the controller. That is the easiest solution that work for me.

1. create external js file eg : `push.js`
2. paste your `onNotificationGCM` function inside `push.js` without any angularjs API like `angular.module` or `.controller`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this one in case of iOS. The reason for this issue is that in `PushPlugin.m` the `callback` property is set to `nil` on killing the app. As a result, the check on [line#202](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/PushPlugin.m#L202) is not satisfied in the `- (void)notificationReceived` callback. The fix for the issue is to instantiate the `PushPlugin` class on opening the push notification every time your app starts. This can be done by registering the push notification plugin on app start. 
Call the `pushNotification.register` method in your javascript everytime your app starts, and this will instantiate the plugin and assign the appropriate `callback` the plugin. I have added the below code to my `Ionic` app's `app.run()` section

```
window.plugins.pushNotification.register(successCallback, errorCallback, {
    badge: 'true',
    sound: 'true',
    alert: 'true',
    ecb: 'window.onNotificationAPN'})
```